# How to count items in list via JavaScript? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I was wondering how can I count list items. I have done this with C# and I have the following code:

```
        SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPList vlist = thisWeb.Lists["Vacancies"];
        SPListItemCollection listitems = vlist.GetItems();

        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        foreach (SPListItem item in listitems)
        {
            if (item["Status"].ToString() == "Completed")
            {
                sum++;
            }

            if (item["Status"].ToString() == "In progress")
            {
                sum1++;
            }
            if (item["Status"].ToString() == "Rejected")
            {
                sum2++;
            }
        }
```

This code works perfect, how can I convert this code into `JavaScript` to do the same function?

I have 3 `Statuses`

- Completed
- In progress
- Rejected

So `int sum` should represent the number of items with `Completed` `Status`,

`int sum1` should represent the number of items with `In progress` `Status`, and

`int sum2` should represent the number of items with `Rejected` `Status`.

The name of list is `Vacancies`

Please help me! Thanks

Comment: Hey i know this is a really old thread but i wanted to know where are you storing the sum as in will it be visible in a column of list or not?

Comment: I have not stored it anywhere, I have just displayed it in a visual web part. But if you want to store it in a SharePoint List it is too easy. `item["StatusCount"] = sum.ToString(); item.Update();` thats it. (I supposed that you have a column called 'StatusCount'). I don't know whether this is for what you are looking.

Comment: Hi I am using this code below but something is not right as i am unable to display the output in webpart. Can u please help. <script type="text/javascript"> var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; $.ajax({ url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('VolunteerMasterList')/items", method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, success: function (data) { if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) { var sum =0; var sum1 =0; var sum2 =0; var sum3 =0; $.each(data.d.results, function(item){ if(item.City === "Earth") sum++; if(item.VolunteerMasterListFileStatus === "Closed") su

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the below code:

```
function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Vacancies');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
    var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(
        collListItem, 
        'Include(Status)'
    );
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var sum =0;
    var sum1 =0;
    var sum2 =0;
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var status = item.get_item('Status');
        if(status=="Completed"){
            sum++;
        }
        else if(status=="In progress"){
            sum1++;
        }
        else if(status=="Rejected"){
            sum2++;
        }        
    }

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

To call this method use it like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to use REST and ajax:

```
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        $.ajax({
                   url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Vacancies')/items",
                   method: "GET",
                   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                   success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                                var sum =0;
                                var sum1 =0;
                                var sum2 =0;
                                $.each(data.d.results, function(item){
                                    if(item.Status === "Completed")
                                      sum++;
                                    if(item.Status === "In Progress")
                                      sum1++;
                                    if(item.Status === "Rejected")
                                      sum2++;
                                });                             
                        }       
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      alert("Error: "+ data);
                 }
          });
```

Comment: thanks my brother, but this works but I can't use REST in my app anyway thanks